# add a color bar legend to a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, color, legending

This has a connection to the previous post here:
[Using a complicated function as color function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52227/puzzled-with-a-color-function)
Also, a recent post of mine appeared here:
[Create a colorbar plot legend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52073/create-a-color-bar-plot-legend)
but I should have solved the problem with the color function before asking the question about color bar.
If opening a new thread goes against the forums policies I apologize.

Thanks to the answers I got, I have now what I wanted

```
h = ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]]), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ImageSize -> 800];
g = Plot3D[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}], {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> (Function[{u, v, z}, Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]]), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All];
Row[{h, Show[g, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

What I further want is to add a color bar to each plot.
Something like

```
Legended[h, BarLegend[{colFun,{min,max}}]] (*version 9*)
```

which does not give the requested color bar.

Also,

```
colourBar = 
  DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 5, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, Range[0, 1, 0.1]}, {None, None}}, 
   ColorFunction -> colFun];
Row[{Show[gr1, ImageSize -> Large], 
  Show[colourBar, ImageSize -> Small]}] (*vesrion 8 alternative*)
```

does not work as well.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Dimitris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{min, max} ={-10, 10};
h2 = ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]]), 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     ImageSize -> 800, 
     PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, {min, max}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

[image]

or

```
Legended[h, BarLegend[{Hue, {min, max}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

Using `Hue` instead of `colFun` as the `ColorFunction` setting in your `colourBar` gives something that you can use as the second argument of  `Legended` in version 8:

```
colourBar2 = DensityPlot[v, {u, 0, 1}, {v, min, max},
                       ColorFunction -> Hue,
                       AspectRatio -> 10, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
                       ImagePadding -> 25,
                       FrameTicks -> {False, Automatic, False, Automatic}]
```

[image]