# BarLegend too large for plot in version 10.3

Tags: graphics, legending

In previous versions, the following code, taken from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52234/add-a-color-bar-legend-to-a-3d-plot) from @kglr, used to give a reasonably sized legend, but in version 10.3 gives a huge legend.

```
lst = {10*Cos[u]*Sin[v], 3*Sin[u]*Sin[v], 2*Cos[v]};

colFun = Function[{u, v}, Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]];

dam = Sqrt[(1296*Cos[u]^4*
       Sin[v]^4)/(900*Cos[v]^2 + 36*Cos[u]^2*Sin[v]^2 + 
        400*Sin[u]^2*Sin[v]^2)^2 + (3600*Cos[u]^2*
       Sin[v]^2*(9*Cos[v]^2 + 4*Sin[u]^2*Sin[v]^2))/(900*Cos[v]^2 + 
        4*(9*Cos[u]^2 + 100*Sin[u]^2)*Sin[v]^2)^2] // FullSimplify;

{min, max} = {-10, 10};
h2 = ParametricPlot3D[lst, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, 
     Hue[Rescale[dam, {0, 1}]]]), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 800, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{Hue, {min, max}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]]
```

Here is the result now,

[image]

Compare with the result from a previous version,

[image]

There is difference between the size of the associated `BarLegend`s.
How can I restore previous performance?

I hope now it is clearer the situation.

Thanks.

Comment: I might be going cross-eyed, but I'm not seeing any difference in the ellipsoids.

Comment: Hello j.m. I am replying through mobile phone. The difference is in the associated bar legends.

Comment: Please edit the question to state explicitly what the issue is.

Comment: I have edit the question.

Comment: I received one more vote for closing since the editing. It is not clear now that an issue does exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the *LegendMarkerSize* option to *BarLegend*, or simply click on the legend to make it active in the output, then drag a handle to change size.

I'd venture something was jiggered in what the default (*Automatic*) setting of that does between versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Weird change of settings:-)!

Comment: Agreed.  I find setting `LegendMarkerSize -> 400` fixes it right up.  It's also odd that `ColorFunctionScaling` is undocumented as an option for `BarLegend`

Comment: @JasonB: Thanks for the editing and the useful comment.